# DocuSign REST API: Check pending envelopes for a user who is DS VIEWER

Tags: docusignapi

First, a call to `GET {{vx}}/accounts/{{accountid}}/folders/`
This gets me the user's Sent folder ID, so I can make a call to `GET {{vx}}/accounts/{{accountid}}/folders/{{folderid}}?status=sent` and `GET {{vx}}/accounts/{{accountid}}/folders/{{folderid}}?status=delivered`

I am able to get envelop details by using above  API Call for the user who is **DS ADMIN , DS SENDER** in permission set...... But when I try to retrieve details for any User with permission Set as **DS VIEWER** then I am getting below error in response:

```
401 ERROR: 

{
  "errorCode": "USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS",
  "message": "This user lacks sufficient permissions to access this resource."
}
```

Any one please help me to resolve the issue.....

Comment: a DS Viewer cannot have sent folder as DS Viewer will be able to just sign the documents so you should check the inbox for that user only, so are you getting above error for Inbox folder as well?

Comment: and how you are calling API, using legacy Auth Header or OAUTH Token?

Comment: I tried using drafts,completed,awaiting_my_signature,out_for_signature folders in the api calls ...But still got same error.... can you please tell me which is for the envelop inbox folder that can be access for DS viewer's inbox

Comment: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/00000000/search_folders/out_for_signature                                                                                                 X-DocuSign-Authentication  :    {"Username":"XXXXXX","Password":"XXXXXXx","IntegratorKey": "XXXXXXXXX","SendOnBehalfOf":"XXXXXXXX"}

Comment: DS Viewer cannot have out_for_signature folders as a DS Viewer cannot send any envelope for signature.

Comment: out_for_signature and even other folders are also not accessible ..........Not sure y

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a user with role **DS Viewer** cannot send envelopes. Therefore, it makes sense that a user with role **DS Viewer** would be prohibited from querying the **Sent** folder via the API -- this is why you're receiving the **401** error response. For more information about DocuSign Permission sets, see the [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/permission-sets.htm).

Comment: Can I access inbox folder for DS-Viewer ?